# Check whether remote URL has a valid image extension

Tags: php, regex, image-uploading, parse-url

How can I check that a remote URL has a valid image extension?

What I want to do is upload images via link using PHP

```
copy('http://website.com/image.jpg', '/upload/filename.jpeg');
```

Code works fine but i want to check whether entered url has a valid image extension.

It should be jpg, png or gif file. Love to see a example of how to do this.

Your help and time is highly appreciated.

Comment: better to also validate the extension is correct for the file, using mime_content_type()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

```
exif_imagetype($image_url);
```

which will output the mime type for validation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `preg_match` to compare the filename to the known list:

```
if (preg_match('/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i', $image_url)) {
    // Successful match!
} else {
    // Not an image file extension
}
```

This will match a string that ends in a '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', or '.gif', whether they're uppercase, lowercase, or mixed case.